# Set TextBox value from ViewBag list in MVC5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

How can I set TextBox value in MVC5 from ViewBag which contains a list? As you can see my list is in ***Viewbag.photos*** and I want to have each value of ***photo.id*** in my TextBox and then pass it to controller

```
 @foreach (var photo in ViewBag.photos)
     {
            @if (@photo.comment != null)
            {
              <h6>@photo.comment</h6>
            }
            else
            {
              <h6> - </h6>
            }
            @Html.TextBox("photoID", @photo.id)

     }
```

Trying to do that I get an error:

> Error CS1973  'HtmlHelper>' has no applicable method
>   named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dinamically dispached.

Maybe there's another workaround?

Comment: Please make a ViewModel and pass that in, instead of using ViewBag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `ViewBag.photos` is a `dynamic` object. The compiler cannot know its type, so you have to manually cast it to its original type.

For example:

```
@Html.TextBox("photoID", (int)photo.id)
```

As a side note (I'm not sure whether this will prevent your code from working, but it's good practice anyway), you also have  bit too many `@`s: to cite Visual Studio, `once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "if" with "@"`. So your final code will look like:

```
 @foreach (var photo in ViewBag.photos)
 {
     if (photo.comment != null)
     {
         <h6>@photo.comment</h6>
     }
     else
     {
         <h6> - </h6>
     }
     @Html.TextBox("photoID", (int)photo.id)
 }
```

You should also consider using ViewModels instead of `ViewBag` to pass data between your controllers and your views.